# Incorporating color into graphical representation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, color-mapping

As shown below, I have a graph. Inside each vertex point (i.e. circle) is a number.
I prepare this graph as such. First I place a circle on the coordinates of each vertex using the following code:

```
plot(vertexCoords(1,:),vertexCoords(2,:),'o',...
  'MarkerFaceColor',[0.90 0.90 0.90],...
   'MarkerSize',30,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','LineWidth',2);
```

Then, I overlay a text object as follows:

```
text(vertexCoords(1,:),vertexCoords(2,:),num2cell(valueVector),...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center');
```

I would like to choose a certain `colormap`, and have the color of each circle be proportional to the number in the circle (the number can range from 0 to 1). How do I go about doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this with the scatter command instead of plot command. Please see below...
        `% for random values

        vertexCoords=rand([5 2]);

        % for arbitrary values

        valuevector=[4 5];


        figure

        % scatter(X,Y,S,C) where X,Y: coordinates, S:size (I set it to 500 here), C:Color

        scatter(vertexCoords(1,:),vertexCoords(2,:),500,(valuevector), 'filled')

        colormap(autumn)

        hold on

        text(vertexCoords(1,:),vertexCoords(2,:),num2cell(valuevector),...

            'HorizontalAlignment','center');`